# repeated parameters with python sphinx

Tags: parameters, python-sphinx

I'm new to python-sphinx, and can't find anything addressing the following:

Suppose I have a function `foo(a,b)` and `bar(a,c)`, such that the parameter `a` has the same description for both functions.

Is it possible to document `a` just once (in `foo`,say) and then copy that description in `bar` to avoid having to update both pieces of text if something in `a`'s description changes?

For example, 
say I document `foo`:

```
def foo(a,b,c):
    """
    a function description.

    :param a: a string, your name
    :param b: something else
    """
```

What would be great is something in `bar`'s documentation like:

```
def bar(a,c)
    """
    another function description.

    :inheritParams foo a: # somehow inherits a's description from foo
    :param c: description for parameter c.
    """
```

even better, if it were `foo(a,b,d)` and `bar(a,c,d)` and I could do (in `bar`'s documentation):

```
:inheritParams foo:  # grabs a and d documentation from function foo
:param c: description for parameter c
```

to have any descriptions of parameters in common with `foo` and `bar` taken from `foo`. That is, it would copy the definition for `a` and `d` from `foo`, and I'd have to document any leftovers (`c`).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of anything like your `:inheritParams:` ideas (though I like them!), but you could probably accomplish the main goal (only documenting the parameter once) using RestructuredText [substitutions](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#id59)

Essentially, you'd set up a substitution definition someplace like so:

```
.. |param_a_docs| <documentation here>
```

and then reference it from the docstring like this:

```
def foo(a,b,c):
    """
    a function description.

    :param a: |param_a_docs|
    :param b: something else
    """
```

This might be a little tricky to get set up right, as you need to make sure that the substitution definition can be found, and throwing docstrings into the mix might make that non-trivial.

One thing to try would be to set up the substitution definitions in a [rst-epilog](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#confval-rst_epilog).

Answer (score 1):

You might try [sphinx-paramlinks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinx-paramlinks/).  It doesn't copy the parameter documentation from `foo` into `bar`, as you asked for, but it does create a hyperlink to the parameter documentation in `foo`.